# why this while true is not looping back

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def erVal():
    print("The value entered is not vaild, enter a valid value")

name = input("Enter your name ")
while True:
 erVal()
 if name.isalpha() is True:
     break
```

does not loop back WHY??

i am trying to display the error message when the user leave the name input blank 
the while loop works but it keeps running printing the errVal

Comment: if user input is alphabet only, `break` is run; cause while loop stop.

Comment: Why do you automatically tell the user their entry is invalid without doing the data validation first?

Comment: You never re-request the input if it's invalid.... Not sure if that's an indentation or logic issue though - difficult to tell from your formatting

Comment: this method has been been suggested, im not very familiar with python, i want to return at the stage where you enter the name if it has been left blank

Comment: because blank is actually considered alpha, since *all* characters are alpha.

Comment: so what should i write instead

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question. Assuming the formatting is correct this code will enter an endless loop if a non alpha value is entered. It will not return to ask for the name again. Entering an alpha value for name will cause the break to be executed which will end the while loop.

I assume you meant something more like the following:

```
def erVal():
  print("The value entered is not valid, enter a valid value.")

while True:
  name = input("Enter your name ")
  if name.isalpha() is True:
    break # will exit the while if name is alpha
  else:
    erVal()
```

Python is very interactive, in the future I suggest you test smaller pieces of the code such as playing with the while loop to see what break does. This will improve your understanding of the code.

Comment: ohh THANKS iv understood the logic  Thank you